# Show GridLines over PreviewView for custom camera app, android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a custom camera app in android studio. I want to implement the Grid Lines to use the rule of thirds feature in my app.
I am using PreviewView to cast the camera stream and want to show the grid lines over PreviewView. Please help me, this is my first camera application and I am new to this.